docker swarm springboot with kafka in same stack other service, no resolvable boot strap urls given in bootstrap.servers issue
I constructed a docker swarm stack.
It has two services in stack
springboot3 application and kafka.
I used apache/kafka's latest docker image.
enter image description here
This is my compose.yml
additional, kafka and springboot app are in the same overlay network
When the springboot app starts,
no resolvable bootstrap urls are given in bootstrap.servers error is fired
enter image description here
As I know, swarm makes DNS by service name.
In springboot image, I try to connect the kafka-1:29092.(I did "docker run -it --network ams myapp:4b9ecffa /bin/bash, i mean it's same network )
It was connected and the return is an empty response
but it means to connect and no resp
What's wrong with my config..?
Am I doing wrong?
Please let me know
construct the same network, and connect to kafka service


Please show code as text, not images 2) Is there a reason you want to use Swarm instead of Kubernetes w/ Operators like Strimzi?


"try to connect the kafka-1:29092" - What does this mean? Kafka isn't an HTTP server, so what response did you expect?

@OneCricketeer


I am working on-premises, so all I can do is take a picture, and my client wants to use Swam.


I just wanted to confirm the container in the same network can find kafka-1:29092.
I mean, DNS can find and connect the IP of Kafka.



Install and use kcat to debug the Kafka protocol. Ping/telnet/netcat are not enough

@OneCricketeer Thank you for your answer!
Can I ask one more question?
After I install KCAT and debug the Kafka protocol, if KCAT is normal, what can I do for this problem?
In your opinion, my configurations are wrong?

If kcat is normal, then any client should be able to connect with the same configuration... Ignoring the fact that kcat isn't JVM based and a few librdkafka configs are different. Just start with kcat -L -b kafka-1:29092, for example
